# llvm new pass manager: how to get -analyze -loops output

Tags: llvm, opt

I used to be able to do:

```
$ opt -analyze -loops app2/app2.ll
Printing analysis 'Natural Loop Information' for function 'rotf':
Loop at depth 1 containing: %4<header><exiting>,%7,%10,%27,%31<latch>,%14,%24
    Loop at depth 2 containing: %10<header><exiting>,%14,%24<latch>
Printing analysis 'Natural Loop Information' for function 'rotf2':
Loop at depth 1 containing: %4<header><exiting>,%7,%10,%27,%31<latch>,%14,%24
    Loop at depth 2 containing: %10<header><exiting>,%14,%24<latch>
Printing analysis 'Natural Loop Information' for function 'main':
Loop at depth 1 containing: %4<header><exiting>,%7,%15,%11,%19,%24,%28,%29<latch>
```

How do I get this information with the new pass manager? The docs are failing me.

```
$ opt  -p print-loops app2/app2.ll
WARNING: You're attempting to print out a bitcode file.
This is inadvisable as it may cause display problems. If
you REALLY want to taste LLVM bitcode first-hand, you
can force output with the `-f' option.

opt: unknown pass name 'print-loops'
$  opt  -p print-analyze-loops app2/app2.ll
WARNING: You're attempting to print out a bitcode file.
This is inadvisable as it may cause display problems. If
you REALLY want to taste LLVM bitcode first-hand, you
can force output with the `-f' option.

opt: unknown pass name 'print-analyze-loops'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the `opt` program has a bug, as pointed out here: https://discourse.llvm.org/t/need-usage-help-w-new-pass-manager-for-opt-analysis-natural-loop-information/75874.

The `LoopPrinterPass` fails to define `isRequired()` so the output is dropped.

A work-around is to generate the LLVM IR code (via clang) with the `-O1` flag, which has other side effects; but then allows `opt` to generate the Natural Loop Information with the following syntax:

```
clang -S -emit-llvm app2.c -O1 -o app2.ll
opt app2.ll -passes="print<loops>" -disable-output
```